# Split a string with a list of keyword matches?

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of delimiters such as
[month, months, years, yrs, years, hrs, hours, mins, min, minute] etc.

And there are input strings such as "2 years 2months", "twenty-two weeks two days" and I would like to break these strings into "2 years" and "2 months" etc. How do it with Java regex?

I tried to approach in the following way and not sure how to proceed from here:

```
String s = "2 mnths 2 years";
String regex = String.join("|", timeWords);
String[] x = s.split(regex);
```

Comment: Please share your solution (non-working) and mention issues with that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a regular expression that leverages a [positive-lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and the "delimiters" you mentioned:

`[\-a-zA-Z\d]+\s?(?=(months|month|yrs|years|hrs|hours|mins|min|minute|weeks|days))`

https://regex101.com/r/Lnid0B/1

Comment: Great! Thank you. Let me read about it. Seems to work :). removing "?=" matches full string including time part, "2 months" etc. Adding for anyone else trying to refer to this answer. also adding "\s" matches "twenty two weeks" instead of "two weeks"